# Is it true that iPhone Enterprise program allows unlimited UDID?

Tags: iphone

Is it true that iPhone Enterprise program allows unlimited UDID? We've hit the 100 limit for our program. We need a lot of testers for this app. Will the enterprise program help us?

Comment: The Enterprise program may allow you to provision an unlimited amount of devices, but the program is not intended for testing, regardless of how many testers you need. If you pay for the program, and only use it for testing, you will be making a very very big waste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. You need a DUNS number to enter the program, but it allows for unlimited devices.

Answer (score -1):

I think you could only get a straight answer about this from someone who has signed an NDA that says they won't talk to people like you.

but if you closely look at the publicly available info...

You don't need to collect the UDIDs of phones when using the Enterprise version of the program, you can use something like Testflight to push it to ANY phone without adding it via Apple's website ( http://manuals.info.apple.com/en_US/Enterprise_Deployment_Guide.pdf )

Since the enterprise version of the program is meant for in-house distribution of apps in large corps, it would pretty much need to allow unlimited installs ( http://developer.apple.com/programs/ios/enterprise/ )